# Birthday Dropdownlist ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, date, drop-down-menu

I am making an input for birthday, how do I make an if-else statement in a dropdownlist?

Months like February only have 28/29 days in it while the rest have 30 or 31...

It would be strange if the user can select month 'April' and day '31'

What I have done is making a label for 'Birthday' ..
added another label for each
'day'
'month'
and 'year'

And 3 dropdownlists for each label...

Comment: Show us the codes. What did you do so far?

Comment: No code, it is just a design in Visual Studio. Sorry >.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically three choices:

1. Write a javascript function to add/remove days from the DropDownList when user selects a month.
2. Set AutoPostBack="true" on the month DropDownList and on the server side add/remove days from the DropDownList. This is the easiest way to go, if you have no experience in writing javascript.
3. Use a control like jQuery datepicker.

Comment: I'll go for the 2nd method for now.. Thank you Ilkka

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using a Javascript/Jquery calendar. These are here to make life simpler for a developer and let him focus on more specific things. There are so many options out there.
One such option is DHTML goodies calendar.
http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?page=calendarScripts

Answer (score 1):

Try this Belzelga......

Add years in your yearDropDownList and months in monthDropDownList... In yearDropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged event check whether the selected year is a leap year or not. Then according to the selection of month add days.

Use the following example code for adding days:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
   dayDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(),i.ToString()));
}
```